# Reversing a string is not matching with the expected output in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have written a python program to reverse the string.
For Example input string is "I am Human" the output will be "namuH ma I"

I have again passed the output to the same function as an input so that the output will be the same string which we have given as input earlier.

Then I am trying to match the given input string to the output but it is not working could you please help.

Program:

```
def reverse(string):
    input_words=string.split(" ")
    temp=input_words[::-1]
    final=[]
    for i in temp:
        x=i[::-1]
        x=x.strip()
        final.append(x)

    output=" ".join(final)
    return(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string="I am Human"
    print(reverse(string))
    output1=reverse(string)
    output2=reverse(output1)    
    print(string)
    print(output2)
    output2=output2.strip()
    if(output1 == output2):
        print("Its maching")
    else:
        print("\n \n there is some issue please check")
```

Output:

```
namuH ma I
I am Human
I am Human


 there is some issue please check
```

Comment: unrelated:  `return ''.join(string[::-1])` would do the same .... as would `''.join(reversed(string))`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing output1 which "namuH ma I" with output2 which I am Human

So it is not obvious will not match.

One more to notice,you using `output2.strip()` which will eliminate "whitespace character" on it
Read more at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

Answer (score 1):

The output2 variable always have reverse value as output1. So obvious it will not match.

Also there is no use of output2=output2.strip() this line

You might wan't to do like this:

```
if(string == output2):
    print("Its maching")
else:
    print("\n \n there is some issue please check")
```